# Firefox mix-blend-mode bug on video (mac)

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox, mix-blend-mode

I am trying to use css mix-blend-mode in combination with video.
It works on every browser, and every device.
BUT it does not work on Mac with firefox browser...

```
See the codepen:
https://codepen.io/heymeindert/pen/oNZjwPa
```

For those without a mac, see the screenshot:
[mix-blend-mode firefox-mac bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv8lS.png)

Does someone know the solution to this problem?
I was thinking about adding a fallback support with '@supports (mix-blend-mode: multiply)', but this will always return true in this case because it is supported on firefox...

Thank you for the help and your time.

EDIT:
Timothy Nickel on Bugzilla confirmed this will be solved in Firefox 89, which will be released June 1 2021.

Comment: I had this working a week or two ago, and now it's not working. For me, it's not working in Firefox on both Mac and PC. The only thing that I have gotten to work, is changing the opacity of the video to 0.98. Hopefully, there is a better solution.

Comment: hmmm.. adding opacity 0.98 does 'fix' it indeed. I made a bug report on bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1710785

Comment: Timothy Nickel on Bugzilla confirmed this will be solved in Firefox 89, which will be released June 1 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to confirm that this has been solved by Firefox as of June 1 2021.